# Change .xla File with MSBuild

Tags: excel, msbuild, build-automation, xla, vba

I'm trying to create a build script for my current project, which includes an Excel Add-in.  The Add-in contains a VBProject with a file modGlobal with a variable version_Number.   This number needs to be changed for every build.  The exact steps:

1. Open XLA document with Excel.
2. Switch to VBEditor mode. (Alt+F11)
3. Open VBProject, entering a password.
4. Open modGlobal file.
5. Change variable's default value to the current date.
6. Close & save the project.

I'm at a loss for how to automate the process.  The best I can come up with is an excel macro or Auto-IT script.  I could also write a custom MSBuild task, but that might get... tricky.  Does anyone else have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way of handling versioning of an XLA file is to use a custom property in Document Properties.  You can access and manipulate using COM as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=224351.

Advantages of this are:

- You can examine the version number without opening the XLA file
- You don't need Excel on your build machine - only the DsoFile.dll component

Another alternative would be to store the version number (possibly other configuration data too) on a worksheet in the XLA file.  The worksheet would not be visible to users of the XLA.  One technique I have used in the past is to store the add-in as an XLS file in source control, then as part of the build process (e.g. in a Post-Build event) run the script below to convert it to an XLA in the output directory.  This script could be easily extended to update a version number in a worksheet before saving.  In my case I did this because my Excel Add-in used VSTO, and Visual Studio doesn't support XLA files directly.

```
'
'   ConvertToXla.vbs
'
'   VBScript to convert an Excel spreadsheet (.xls) into an Excel Add-In (.xla)
'
'   The script takes two arguments:
'
'   - the name of the input XLS file.
'
'   - the name of the output XLA file.
'
Option Explicit
Dim nResult
On Error Resume Next
nResult = DoAction
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo Err.Description
    Wscript.Quit 1
End If
Wscript.Quit nResult

Private Function DoAction()

    Dim sInputFile, sOutputFile

    Dim argNum, argCount: argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count

    If argCount < 2 Then
        Err.Raise 1, "ConvertToXla.vbs", "Missing argument"
    End If

    sInputFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
    sOutputFile = WScript.Arguments(1)

    Dim xlApplication

    Set xlApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Resume Next 
    ConvertFileToXla xlApplication, sInputFile, sOutputFile
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
        Dim nErrNumber
        Dim sErrSource
        Dim sErrDescription
        nErrNumber = Err.Number
        sErrSource = Err.Source
        sErrDescription = Err.Description
        xlApplication.Quit
        Err.Raise nErrNumber, sErrSource, sErrDescription
    Else
        xlApplication.Quit
    End If

End Function

Public Sub ConvertFileToXla(xlApplication, sInputFile, sOutputFile)

    Dim xlAddIn
    xlAddIn = 18 ' XlFileFormat.xlAddIn

    Dim w
    Set w = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open(sInputFile,,,,,,,,,True)
    w.IsAddIn = True
    w.SaveAs sOutputFile, xlAddIn
    w.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Another way to version an XLA, is to store the version number in the property of commmand bar /toolbar if you have one (eg store the verison in the tooltip). The VBA code can get out of sync with the code xla command bar if you swap the xla files. Compare this tool tip with the VBA code - have a function in the code which compare with the tooltip  version with the code.  From there you can then delete the command bar and rebuild it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how to do exactly what you have requested. But guessing the goal you have in mind there are a few possibilities.

**1)** Make part (or all) of your Globals a separate text file that is distributed with the .XLA I would use this for external references such as the version of the rest of your app. Write this at build time and distribute, and read on the load of the XLA.

**2)** I'm guessing your writing the version of the main component (ie: the non XLA part) of your application. If this is tru why store this in your XLA? Why not have the main part of the app allow certain version of the XLA to work. Version 1.1 of the main app could accept calls from Version 7.1 - 8.9 of the XLA.

**3)** If you are just looking to update the XLA so it gets included in your version control system or similar (i'm guessing here) maybe just touch the file so it looks like it changed.

If it's the version of the rest of the app that you are controlling i'd just stick it in a text file and distribute that along with the XLA.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code in the xla programmatically from within Excel. You will need a reference to the 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility..' component.

The examples on [Chip Pearson's excellent site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) should get you started.